# JQuery: Array push not behaving properly on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Having issues with a sort method in Jquery. On chrome, divs are sorted correctly and element are moved on the page. On firefox, elements do not move at all (But appear to have refreshed on the page) IE, the elements disappear completely.

Here is my code:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.sortByDate = function( elements, order ) {
    var arr = [];
    elements.each(function() {
        var obj = {},
            $el = $( this ),
            time = $el.find( "time" ).text(),
            date = new Date( $.trim( time ) ),
            timestamp = date.getTime();

            obj.html = $el[0].outerHTML;
            obj.time = timestamp;

            arr.push( obj );

    });

    var sorted = arr.sort(function( a, b ) {

        if( order == "ASC" ) {
            return a.time > b.time;
        } else {
            return b.time > a.time;
        }

    });

    return sorted;
};

$(function() {
    var $newer = $( "#newer" ),
        $older = $( "#older" ),
        $content = $( "#list" ),
        $elements = $( ".searchlock" );

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var elements = $.sortByDate( $elements, "DESC" );
            var html = "";
            for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
                html += elements[i].html;
            }
            $content[0].innerHTML = html;
            $( this ).addClass( "selected" ).
            siblings().
            removeClass( "selected" );
            return false; 

        })

        $newer.click(function() {
            var elements = $.sortByDate( $elements, "DESC" );
            var html = "";
            for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
                html += elements[i].html;
            }
            $content[0].innerHTML = html;
            $( this ).addClass( "selected" ).
            siblings().
            removeClass( "selected" );
            return false;

        });

        $older.click(function() {
            var elements = $.sortByDate( $elements, "ASC" );
            var html = "";
            for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
                html += elements[i].html;
            }
            $content[0].innerHTML = html;
            $( this ).addClass( "selected" ).
            siblings().
            removeClass( "selected" );
            return false;

        });
});
})( jQuery );
```

*Things I have Tried*:
moving var arr outside of the function, making it global: did not work

Here is a test site i have out on codio:
 http://jargon-cool.codio.io:3000/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This might have something to do with nested `$(document).ready()`s? Also, a custom sort function should return a negative number, `0` or a positive number, not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Tried your changes, with no avail :( Can you elaborate more on the boolean? The false is there so the page remains put and doesn't jump to the top upon its call.

Comment: You can read about `sort()` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Returning a boolean will sort incorrectly. A boolean is converted either to `0` (= equal) or `1` (= larger than), "smaller than" case can't be returned with booleans. Did you remove the `$(document).ready()` wrapper from the code inside `$(function() {...})`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i did remove the $(document).ready(), and i pushed changed to my test site on codio @ http://jargon-cool.codio.io:3000/

Comment: If i had to take a guess, i have to think its something to do with  obj.html = $el[0].outerHTML; - dont think this works with any other browser besides chrome?

Comment: Nope, [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility) was implemented in IE4, and in FF it has been available since version 11.

Comment: The code i originally adapted was taken from here: http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/xdLak
As you can see, it works fine here. Not sure why i am having problems, but I have a lot more elements in my div's that are floating around

Comment: Ignore the page jumping to the top issue. dont let that be the reason for using a boolean. im assuming you are using a link structured like `<a href="#" id="newer/older">Newer/Older</a>` you can solve the jump to the top using `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of  `href="#"`